# MySQL use data from 2 tables to show 1 table

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, left-join

How is it possible to show all orders which are not completely paid off related to a client? for e.g.

SHOW ALL order details of ‘unpaid’ ORDERS for CLIENT ‘50’

table: orders

| id | order_total | client_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15.00 | 50 |
| 2 | 18.50 | 50 |
| 3 | 40.00 | 50 |

table: order_payments

| order_id | total_paid | payment_status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15.00 | paid |
| 2 | 3.50 | open |
| 2 | 12.00 | paid |

*** NOTE: Not every order has a registered payment. No registered payment should be considered "open" ***

Expected results:

| order_id | order_total | client_id | outstanding |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15.00 | 50 | 0 |
| 2 | 18.50 | 50 | 6.50 |
| 3 | 40.00 | 50 | 40.00 |

Comment: I think what you are trying to find is the LEFT JOIN. So you can LEFT JOIN the order_payments. As I see it's possible that there are many payments to one order -> 1:n

If you want to sum it up and receive one row each order you can do it like this:

SELECT SUM(op.total_paid) FROM orders o LEFT JOIN order_payments op ON o.id = op.order_id WHERE op.payment_status = 'open'

Comment: Oh you also want it grouped by the clients so you would need to group it:

SELECT SUM(op.total_paid) FROM orders o LEFT JOIN order_payments op ON o.id = op.order_id WHERE op.payment_status = 'open'
GROUP BY o.client_id

Comment: Yes correct, many payments to one order. But the left join needs to sum the total amount paid and check if it exceeds the order_total

Comment: @ErgestBasha edited the topic with expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your tables and I would do it like this:

```
SELECT o.id AS order_id, o.order_total, o.client_id, 
(o.order_total - SUM(IF(op.payment_status = 'paid', op.total_paid, 0))) AS outstanding 
FROM orders o
   LEFT JOIN order_payments op ON o.id = op.order_id
GROUP BY o.id
ORDER BY outstanding ASC
```

Comment: Works amazing, thanks. What about if I would like to show only the open orders for one specific client id.

Comment: You can handle this in a WHERE. So you do it like this:

SELECT o.id AS order_id, o.order_total, o.client_id, 
(o.order_total - SUM(IF(op.payment_status = 'paid', op.total_paid, 0))) AS outstanding 
FROM orders o
   LEFT JOIN order_payments op ON o.id = op.order_id
WHERE o.client_id = 50
GROUP BY o.id
ORDER BY outstanding ASC

Note that you should check your id first. SQL-Injection should be a topic for you as a beginner in MYSQL. You can pass the 50 as variable. But you have to check the variable first like if its numeric or slt.
Dont forget to set the question as answered ;)

Comment: Tried to use it in combination with GROUP BY o.client_id, doesn't seem to show correct data. It doesn't count up all outstanding totals.
`SELECT o.id AS order_id, o.order_total, o.client_id, (o.order_total - SUM(IF(op.payment_status = 'paid', op.total_price, 0))) AS outstanding FROM company_pos_orders o LEFT JOIN company_payments op ON o.id = op.order_id GROUP BY o.client_id ORDER BY outstanding ASC; `

Comment: Did you change your data? Or do you get an error?

Comment: No data not changed, just the naming of columns/tables. Above code is not showing errors, it shows incorrect "outstanding" data. Looks like if I group it by o.client_id it's not counting all the "open amounts" for the client in "outstanding"

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recent enough version of MySQL (>= 8.0.14), I would  recommend [a lateral join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html):

```
select o.*, op.total_paid, o.order_total - op.total_paid outstanding
from orders o
cross join lateral (
    select coalesce(sum(op.total_paid), 0) total_paid 
    from order_payments op 
    where payment_status = 'open' and op.order_id = o.id
) op
```

The subquery after the `lateral` keyword searches the relevant rows in the payment table for each order, and returns the total paid (or 0 if there are no rows, or no valid payment).

Lateral joins are a powerful feature in SQL (that took a long time coming into MySQL). They are efficient, flexible and expressive, and come handy in many such situations.

Comment: What is the difference to the normal left join? I have a feeling that I need to learn this :)

Comment: @Florianb: the documentation I linked in my answer is a good starting point (it has explanations and an actual example). For starters: *A derived table cannot normally refer to (depend on) columns of preceding tables in the same FROM clause. As of MySQL 8.0.14, a derived table may be defined as a lateral derived table to specify that such references are permitted.*

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    orderss.id, orderss.ORDER_TOTAL, orderss.CLIENT_ID,
    nvl(A.Total_paid,0) AS TOTAL_PAID,
    Orderss.ORDER_TOTAL-nvl(A.Total_paid,0) AS TOTAL_OUTSTANDING
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT id,payment_status,Total_paid
     FROM order_paymentss
     GROUP BY id,payment_status,Total_paid
     HAVING Payment_status='paid'
    ) A 
    ON orderss.id=A.id;
```

This should easily work.